# Custom Options - styling

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, admin-panel, styles

How to change the style of the custom options in magento 1.9, like font-size, etc.

Can this be done from the admin panel?

Comment: You can't do that. Depending on the theme you are using, you have to change your css files.